# Issues With Jquery Form Validations

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to do form validation using Jquery, unfortunately neither I am not able to display the null field empty message nor I am not able to prevent user from leaving fields blank.

I am using the following query for validations

```
 $("#frm").validate( {  
                    rules : {  
                        empName : "required"  
                    }  
                });
```

I have put a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsh3b/3/) using JSFiddle

Any help is highly appreciable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use the anchor but then you have to submit the form manually ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsh3b/8/)).
You also shouldn't initialize the validation on a click event. Initialize it on load and then just submit the form to trigger validation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm").validate( {  
        ignore: '*:not([name])', //Fixes your name issue
        rules : {  
            empName : "required"  
        },
        messages: {
            empName: {
                required: "Please enter name"
            }
        }  
    });  

    $("#saveB").click(function(){
        $("#frm").submit();    
    });   
});
```

Or you can also use `valid` without submit the form ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsh3b/11/)):

```
  $("#saveB").click(function(){
        $("#frm").valid();
  });
```

Comment: Marcel , withoutform submit it is not possible to trigger the validation right?

Comment: I am using a Jquery plugin called JeasyUI and input is basically a autocomplete input text. When I submit I am getting the following error `Failed to validate, found an element with no name assigned. See console for element reference.  <input type="text" class="combo-text validatebox-text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 129px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px;"> has no name assigned`

Comment: Then give it a name. For example `name="blabla"`.

Comment: In code I have specified as `<input name="empName" id="empName" class="required">`

Comment: Updated answer again, have a look at `ignore: '*:not([name])',`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29436/discussion-between-polppan-and-marcel-gwerder)

Comment: If you're going to use an anchor in place of a button, at least use jQuery's `preventDefault()`.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/Qsh3b/20/

Answer (score 1):

It's your anchor causing the problem - namely it's `href` attribute. My advice would be to use an alternative validation trigger, such as an input like `<button>`.

[**Working jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsh3b/4/)

Comment: Zenith I wouldn't able to to do with anchor tag to have form validations?

Comment: @Polppan You can do, but it's not as simple as using inputs.